# Merging 2 videos in android

Tags: android, video, mp4parser

I want to merge or mix 2 videos in android app. I tried using mp4parser but it is appending the video and I want to mix the frames. I want video to be mixed by 10 seconds from one video and 10 seconds from 2nd video.

Any piece of code would be appreciated.

Comment: look for ffmpeg for android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mp4parser library to append videos. The problem is the limited documentation.

here is the link of mp4parser lib
https://code.google.com/archive/p/mp4parser/

or

You can use ffmpeg which is providing amazing features to the users to compress, split, merge and all kind of video/ audio editing/compressing/trancoding,etc. Version 1.1 (ffmpeg fire flower) onwards concat demuxer has been added to it, This is working fine in my android application.

https://ffmpeg.org/

gihub sample : https://github.com/hai046/hai_ffmpeg

Comment: I am able to append the video using mp4parser but I want to trim the vidoe in multiple clips and then merge them. I want to to take 1 clip from 1 video and 1 clip from 2nd video and then merge them . is this possible using mp4parser?